# BEMF and zero crossing point detection

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, hall-effect, phase-shift

I am trying to control a BLDC motor without sensors using BEMF method and zero crossing detection. I managed to detect the zero crossing point but I am not sure if it is correct. I read that the hall sensors signal and BEMF ZCP have a phase shift of 30 degree. 
I measured the output of one hall sensor and the zero crossing point for the same phase (B):
[image]

How can I be sure that I really detect the zero crossing point ? Right now the motor runs in open loop, first I want to be sure when to switch to the next state because if I do it wrong it might burn the MOSFETs.

Comment: Measure in both directions to determine if the Hall sensor error is usable..

Comment: See DRV10970 which supports both 0 and 30 deg Hall sensors if 3 sensors http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa695/slaa695.pdf